# How to install different versions of your own Android app on your phone without deleting the previous one

Tags: android, version

I would like to install different versions of an App on my phone by using Android Studio and I always changed the app name in the Android Manuscript. However, when I install the new version, the old version automatically gets deleted without Android asking me if I want to delete it and altough the name of the apps are not the same. Do you have any idea, how I can have multiple versions of the same app (with different names) installed on my phone without changing the name of the whole project?

Here is my Android Manuscipt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.drinkserver">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="app_name_3"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I changed the label `android:label="app_name_3"` all the time but still, the old apps get deleted.

**Reminder**: Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Just change your app package name into something.

Comment: @Thanks Maverick for your answer. I tried to change the label `package="com.example.newName">` and now I get the error in the manuscript "
Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.newName.MainActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries"

Comment: When you're changing the package name, you'll also change the package folder names in your java main folder.

Comment: @MaverickFabroa: Thanks for your comment. Is there no way to do that without changing the name of the whole project? I mean it is still the same project and only a different version of the app should be installed on the smartphone

Comment: @MaverickFabroa: Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.